# Remove server string from response to address error message disclosure

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, http-headers

Currently, when I call a REST API, built on SpringBoot, I am getting `Server: openresty` as one of the response header. As per the security measures, we need this Server: header not to be shown in the response. I tried:

```
try {
    chain.doFilter(request, new HttpServletResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response) {
        public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
            if (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("Server")) {
                super.setHeader(name, value);
            }
        }
    });
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But seems like it is not even coming inside this segment. Any other way to remove a response header?

Comment: You tried that where? Additionally, a simple Google search for "openresty" suggests that it's a proxy server sitting in front of your Spring Boot application.

Comment: @chrylis Sorry, forgot to mention. I have added this in the spring controller layer, just before returning the response object. And yes, whatever that openresty is, I want to remove the server header itself from the response header.

Comment: Have you tried `more_clear_headers Server` in your proxy config?

Comment: Sorry but where is the proxy config located?

Comment: Pretty sure it's being added by *a different server*.